# Scrapy--Can not import the items to my spider (No module name behance.items)

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

i'm new to scrapy and when  running the spider to crawl [behance](https://www.behance.net/)

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from behance.items import BehanceItem
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.http import TextResponse

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "behance"
    #allowed_domains = ["behance.com"]
    start_urls = [

        "https://www.behance.net/gallery/29535305/Mind-Your-Monsters",


    ]


    def __init__ (self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def parse(self, response):

            self.driver.get(response.url)
            response = TextResponse(url=response.url, body=self.driver.page_source, encoding='utf-8')
            item = BehanceItem()
            hxs = Selector(response)

            item['link'] = response.xpath("//div[@class='js-project-module-image-hd project-module module image project-module-image']/@data-hd-src").extract()

            yield   item

process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
})

process.crawl(DmozSpider)
process.start()
```

I am getting following error on command line when i run my crawler

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/davy/behance/behance/spiders/behance_spider.py", line 3, in 
    from behance.items import BehanceItem

ImportError: **No module named behance.items**

My directory structure:

```
behance/
├── behance
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── items.py
│   ├── pipelines.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   └── spiders
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── behance_spider.py
-── scrapy.cfg
```

Comment: what's the content of your items.py file?

Comment: @narko  `import scrapy


class BehanceItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    link =  scrapy.Field()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running your spider by using this command:

```
scrapy crawl behance
```

Or change your spider file:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from behance.items import BehanceItem
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.http import TextResponse

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class BehanceSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "behance"
    allowed_domains = ["behance.com"]
    start_urls = [

    "https://www.behance.net/gallery/29535305/Mind-Your-Monsters",


]


    def __init__ (self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def parse(self, response):

        self.driver.get(response.url)
        response = TextResponse(url=response.url, body=self.driver.page_source, encoding='utf-8')
        item = BehanceItem()
        hxs = Selector(response)

        item['link'] = response.xpath("//div[@class='js-project-module-image-hd project-module module image project-module-image']/@data-hd-src").extract()

        yield   item
```

And create another python file in the directory where your `settings.py` file resides.

`run.py`

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

process.crawl("behance")
process.start()
```

Now run this file as you run normal python script. `python run.py`

Comment: i know use command that is also can work   but i want to run spider within python script instead of using command

Comment: Then I would suggest you to change your spider file and run the spider through `CrawlerProcess`. I'm updating the answer have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to your python path:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/davy/behance/
```